# Regex find all XML values based on subvalue

Tags: regex, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML code:

```
<quantity1 value="foo" name="bar">
   <subquantity duration="2">
        <parameter unit="meters" />
   </subquantity>
</quantity1>
```

I want to export all `name`s for further analysis in another document, but only if they have a certain subvalue.  For example, how can I use regex to find all `name`s based on if `unit="meters"`?

Bonus points if you can instruct how to do this in Notepad++.  Open to other suggestions/SO posts as well.

Comment: Never use RegEx to query XML. It's unsafe by design.

Comment: Use XSLT instead to pull out what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions [are wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/290085) for parsing XML.

Use XPath in XSLT or a scripting language or xmlstarlet instead.

Examples:

- `//quantity1[subquantity/parameter/@unit="meters"]/@name`
- `//*[*/*/@unit="meters"]/@name`
- `//*[.//@unit="meters"]/@name`